# How can I get the amount of memory that remains for Redis

Tags: php, redis

With `REDIS` command [`INFO`](http://redis.io/commands/info) i can get current memory usage:

For Example:

```
  'used_memory' => int 600832
  'used_memory_human' => string '586.75K' (length=7)
  'used_memory_rss' => int 1998848
  'used_memory_peak' => int 845056
  'used_memory_peak_human' => string '825.25K' (length=7)
  'used_memory_lua' => int 31744
```

And now i want to check how much memory left for `Redis`.
Only way i see is to check  `cat /proc/meminfo` and compare it.
Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in Redis to supply you with this information.

The available memory is machine-wide. Parsing `/proc/meminfo` is indeed a good way to get this info.

See here for a python example: [nagios plugins check_memory](https://github.com/kumina/nagios-plugins-kumina/blob/master/check_memory.py)

We use a similar script on our dedicated redis machines (which run several redis-server instances a piece), that send alerts to our in-house exception handling portal when our memory limit is reached.

Kind regards, TW